# Temperature Sensor IoT device that support cloud integration

Tags: smart-home, mqtt, sensors, aws-iot, azure

I am looking for an IoT temperature sensor that does the following:

- Able to Communicate with cloud platform (aws, azure etc)
- Does not require a lot of programming. The device should be preconfigured.
- Should be able to Monitor the surrounding temperature and record the data.
- It should be able to access the temperature log and perform certain actions when the temperature is not in the given range or higher than critical/ maximum temperature specified. Eg:

  - send notification via mail
  - sound an alarm

I found a Company that provides these devices but the pricings are too high, giving Rs. 20,000 for just a temperature sensor is crossing the budget we have set.

If anyone has worked on such devices can they please share a solution/product. Thank you.

Comment: there are many web based temperature sensor projects on the internet ... please examine some of them

Comment: if you are seeking a ready made product, then you asked at the wrong place ... this site is not for shopping questions

Comment: tasmota based product, but you need some general it knowledge

Comment: links to the project https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota you can try home assistant , if you found these term alien to you then you are in the wrong place